# Reading through file 4 lines at a time

Tags: python, file, while-loop, lines

```
import os
filePath = "C:\\Users\\siba\\Desktop\\1x1x1.blb"
BrickName = (os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filePath))[0])

import sys
def ImportBLB(filePath):
    file = open(filePath)
    line = file.readline()

    while line:
        if(line == "POSITION:\n"):
            POS1 = file.next()
            POS2 = file.next()
            POS3 = file.next()
            POS4 = file.next()
            sys.stdout.write(POS1)
            sys.stdout.write(POS2)
            sys.stdout.write(POS3)
            sys.stdout.write(POS4)
            return

        line = file.readline()
    file.close()
    return

ImportBLB(filePath)
```

I'm attempting to read through the file four lines at a time upon locating the line "POSITION:", but this only outputs the first four lines due to the return statement ending the loop.

Removing the return statement gives me a "ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data" error, how would I get around this?

Comment: Just replace the `line = file.readline()` statements with `line = file.next()` so you're not mixing them -- or do the reverse and make all the calls to be to `file.readline()`.

Comment: If I do readLine(), I get "AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readLine'", if I do next(), I get "line = file.next()
StopIteration"

Comment: That's because the method's name is `readline` not `readLine`. A `StopIteration` at end-of-file is normal, and can be ignored with a `try/except StopIteration: pass` construct around the whole `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your logic with this:

```
with open(file_path) as f:
    while True:
        try:
            line = next(f)
        except StopIteration:
            break # stops the moment you finish reading the file
        if not line:
            break # stops the moment you get to an empty line
        if line == "POSITION:\n":
            for _ in range(4):
                sys.stdout.write(next(f))
```

**edit:** As your comment stated, you want 4 variables; 1 for each line. replace the last part with this:

```
lines = [next(f) for _ in range(4)]
```

This will give you a list with 4 items (the 4 lines you want) if you would prefer individual variables:

```
line1, line2, line3, line4 = [next(f) for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: You could just use `for line in f`

Comment: I'm trying to go about this in a way I understand the code completely; and this format would just confuse me. Also, I need to apply all 4 lines to a seperate variable.

Answer (score 0):

Used a little bit of both of the above suggestions, and this is now my code;

import os
filePath = "C:\Users\siba\Desktop\1x1x1.blb"
BrickName = (os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filePath))[0])

import sys
def ImportBLB(filePath):
    file = open(filePath)
    line = file.next()

```
while line:
    if(line == "POSITION:\n"):
        POS1 = file.next()
        POS2 = file.next()
        POS3 = file.next()
        POS4 = file.next()
        sys.stdout.write(POS1)
        sys.stdout.write(POS2)
        sys.stdout.write(POS3)
        sys.stdout.write(POS4)

    try:
        line = file.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
file.close()
return
```

ImportBLB(filePath)

Comment: I think you could save yourself a lot of effort by reading the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) section on loops.  Whenever you find that you're duplicating code except for minor changes, you're violating the DRY ("Don't Repeat Yourself") principle, and that's usually a sign you're working at the wrong level of abstraction.